# Categorical encoded variables in scikit-learn diabetes dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering, feature-scaling, categorical-encoding

When using `sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes`, the sex variable which is categorical, is scaled to continuous values. Is it even legal to scale such variables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly legal to do so. Scaling such binary variables does not change the shape of its histogram and the shape is all that matters to most models.